# I'm inserting null records when I didn't input anything

Tags: coldfusion, null, cfquery

I'm trying to first check for NULLs and if the value is NULL skip the `INSERT`. But that is not what's happening. The code is inserting NULL records even though I have not input anything in the form field.  It's almost like it's recognizing something that does not exist.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif form.TBCom is not ""> 
    <cfquery name="TestTBComm" datasource="TrenaTest">
        INSERT INTO Comment1 (
            UniqueNum,
            ComTyp,
            Comments )
        SELECT 
           '#UniqueNum#',
           '#TBComV#',
           '#TBCom#'
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Is your check for null taking place in the cfif?

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but any reason you are using a `SELECT` with static values instead of a `VALUES` clause? Or is there more to the query than what was posted?

Answer (score 6):

The previous answers are correct, in that when testing general strings, NULL check don't apply in CF.  You either test for length or value.

That query scared me enough that I thought a complete example was necessary.  It is imperative that EVERY field of a query whose data is supplied by the user be contained within a CFQUERYPARAM.  Look up the term "[sql injection](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=woP0DdS0qqzVGjldobHqww&cp=7&gs_id=q&xhr=t&q=sql+injection&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=sql+inj&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=fd914e5a4ec503ba&biw=1680&bih=965)" for the reasons why.

This query should work for you:

```
<cfquery name="TestTBComm" datasource="TrenaTest">
    INSERT INTO Comment1 (
        UniqueNum,
        ComTyp,
        Comments )
    VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#FORM.UniqueNum#">
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#FORM.TBComV#" NULL="#!Len(FORM.TBComV)#">
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#FORM.TBCom#" NULL="#!Len(FORM.TBCom)#">
    )
</cfquery>
```

In the NULL parameter, note the "!", which inverses the result of the LEN() function.

Comment: Agreed about cfqueryparam. Though they may need to tweak the cfsqltypes. It is unclear whether the "UniqueNum" column is numeric or string. The name implies numeric, but the value is quoted in the original example. So it could go either way :)

Comment: Yes, Leigh...I should have stated my assumptions about data types.  Thanks.

Comment: Mike - I love that "!len(form.tbcomv)" example... I always end up writing a function for that. Never thought of adding the evaluation operand to it. nice!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you wish to skip the insert when the form field is empty, `trim()` it first and check the length. Then skip the insert if the length is 0:

```
 <cfif len(trim(form.TBCom))>
      not empty. do the insert ...
 </cfif>
```

As an aside, you do not need `cfoutput` tags around the `cfquery`. The variables will be evaluated automatically. Also, you should be using [`cfqueryparam`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) on all user supplied parameters ([see Mike's answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11780203/104223)) and be sure to scope your variables ie use `form.TBCom` not just `TBCom`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try removing the cfoutput tags and see what happens.  I have never used cfqueryparam so I'll have to do some investigation. I'm current checking the len but, I will also do the len(trim(form.TBCom) and see what happens.

Comment: Well the code above checks the `value` rather than the `length`, which is different. Also, I am assuming you meant "empty string" rather than `null`, which as Mark mentioned is a different concept.

Answer (score 0):

The code above would NOT insert nulls in the 3 columns specified (uniqueNum, comTyp, and comments).  It would insert empty strings - which is not the same thing as a NULL.

Also - I agree with Leigh that the proper syntax should be:

```
   <cfquery name="TestTBComm" datasource="TrenaTest">
        INSERT INTO Comment1 (
            UniqueNum,
            ComTyp,
            Comments )
        VALUES (
           '#UniqueNum#',
           '#TBComV#',
           '#TBCom#'
           )
    </cfquery>
```

So... where are these nulls occuring? If they are in other columns in the DB (That are not a part of this query) it's because you are not inserting into those columns and they are set to "allow nulls" and have no "default" value.

Comment: Well I believe I have to check for nulls and empty strings.  The only way it has worked is when I check both.

Comment: What do you mean by check both? Because generally speaking CF does not really have the concept of `null` like a database does.

Comment: Okay.  I did everything that everyone recommended except for the cfqueryparam and everything worked out great.  Thanks for everything.

Comment: You should definitely add the `cfqueryparam` asap. See Mike's answer for an example. Note you may need to tweak the `cfsqltype`s to match the actual data types of your columns.

Comment: I'll give th cfqueryparam a try and see how it works.  The uniquenum is autogenerated, therefore, the user is not inputing that field.  It's also hidden so they won't ever see the field at all.

Comment: Ok I added the cfqueryparam and it worked just fine.  Thank you so much.